# conditionally make the 2nd axios call happen based on a first

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to make it so that I can look at the returned object from the first axios call, and if empty, continue to the 2nd (if it's not empty I will craft an error message)

Basically, the 2nd axios call should only happen if the userStatus object is empty. Both axios calls work independently but how Can I properly make this work so that I can hit the 2nd call if the object is empty?

Currently I get a 200 on the first axios call and an empty userStatus object in my console but the 2nd call doesn't happen

```
changeStatus: function(event) {

  let user = this.auth_user;

  axios.get('/user/' + user + '/status')
  .then((response) => {
      this.userStatus = response.data
  })

  if(this.userStatus.length < 1){

    let data = {
        id: event.id,
        status: 'A'
    };

    axios.post('/status/change',data)
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.success == false) {
            this.errors = [];
            const errorLog = Object.entries(response.data.errors);
            for (var i = errorLog.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                console.log(errorLog[i][1][0]);
                this.errors.push(errorLog[i][1][0]);
            }
        }
    })


  }else{
    console.dir('No');
  }
},
```

Comment: Axios is async: move everything inside the `.then` callback or use `async/await`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that your code is being executed *synchronously* (essentially line-by-line), while axios calls are ***a***synchronous. So while your first axios call is still executing in the background, the statement `if(this.userStatus.length < 1)` gets evaluated – before your first call has returned.

If your second call is conditioned upon the result of your first call, you would need to make your second call ***inside*** the `.then()` handler of your first call:

```
changeStatus: function(event) {
  let user = this.auth_user;

  axios.get('/user/' + user + '/status')
    .then((response) => {
      this.userStatus = response.data;

      if(this.userStatus.length < 1) {
        let data = {
          id: event.id,
          status: 'A'
        };

        axios.post('/status/change',data)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success == false) {
              this.errors = [];
              const errorLog = Object.entries(response.data.errors);

              for (var i = errorLog.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                console.log(errorLog[i][1][0]);
                this.errors.push(errorLog[i][1][0]);
              }
            }
          });
       } else {
         console.dir('No');
       }
    });
},
```

Comment: I'm confused about your statement that the second call is "happening synchronously", and if I'm confused, I would say OP is as well. AFAIK, both calls are *async* and both calls are "happening" *synchronously*. You might need to reword that part. Nonetheless, good answer.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, It makes sense to me, but I can see how it could be confusing. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: This worked perfectly and I don't know WHY I didn't realize to do this. Thanks so much

Comment: @TomN. Sometimes the best thing about Stack Overflow is just getting another pair of eyes on your code. 